# Problem with bulk items insert in SPList (works fine for 200 but not if item exceeds )

Tags: splistitem, bulk

```
var itemArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var items = data[i].split(",");
                downloadID = items[0].trim();
                noOfDownloads = items[1];

                                        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
                        oListItem.set_item('DownloadID', downloadID);
                        oListItem.set_item('NoOfDownloads', noOfDownloads);
                        oListItem.update();
                        itemArray[i] = oListItem;
                        clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);

                                           }
                }
            }
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFileUploadSucceeded1),
                        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFileUploadFailed1)
                    );
        }
```

Please suggest, what could be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rupesh,

You need to use [ProcessBatchData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.processbatchdata%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for your scenario if you can use server side code.

If you want to use only CSOM the below code works just fine. I have tested it already

```
    $(document).ready(function() {    
           ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(abc, "sp.js");
           });

    function abc()
    {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        var mListName=  "TestList";
        mList = web.get_lists().getByTitle(String(mListName));
          context.load(mList);

    for (var i = 1; i < 250; i++) {
                            var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
                            var oListItem = mList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
                            oListItem.set_item('Title', 'Title' + i.toString());
                            oListItem.update();

                            context.load(oListItem);

                                               }


                context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

    }


function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Items inserted!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I want to do by CSOM only :) above code looks same as of mine, except context.load(oListItem); . I am loading thru array because sometimes throws error "oListItem has been changed already".                    
did you check your code for  i < 500...? which is an issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

As you are hitting the server to frequently to Add items, SharePoint sometimes do stop the execution in between. I faced the similar issue when i was deleting items from the list. 
Your code is fine, I would suggest you to add a few moments of delay after adding like 50/100 items. Its even better if you can do an asynchronous loop but it will require you to write new code.

Comment: As I understand, I am not hitting server frequently here. because single async call going thru - executeQueryAsync, which is out of loop body.
I can add 500 items if  call executeQueryAsync inside loop which will send multiple request to server which I don't want to do. My problem is why works fine if items are 200/250 but not if its 300/400/500.